# Default CSS being overridden by media query when screen size is less than MQ

Tags: css, media-queries

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong and it's probably something stupid. But I have a logo that I'm trying to resize based on the screen size. But for some reason, the default (mobile) style isn't taking effect and instead is using the media query style for the next size (tablet-vertical). Despite the screen size being less than the tablet size.

I'm using Google Chrome's inspector for breakpoints.

Here's what I have:

```
h1.logo {font-size: 2em;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1.logo {font-size: 1.25em;}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1130px) {
  h1.logo {font-size: 1.2em;}
}
```

For some reason the 1.25em size is overruling the 2em size when it should be the other way around. Even when my screen width is less than 768px.

Comment: Try using `max-width` I always mix these two up :D

Comment: `min-width: 768px` means from `768px` and above, so it won't take effect unless the viewport is above or equal `768px`

Comment: @ZohirSalak, yes, I know. It's not supposed to be affecting anything below 768px. But at screen sizes below 768px, the H1 is applying 1.25em rather than 2em.

Comment: Edit your question with a code snippet that reproduces the issue

Answer (score 0):

In this case, `min-width` will always overrule the 2em `font-size` property because it's the initial screen size that you want the style to apply.

In your example you are saying that **STARTING AT 768px & ABOVE** (min-width), h1.logo `font-size` property should be `1.25em`.

If you want h1.logo `font-size` decrease to 1.25em below 768px screen sizes, you should use `max-width`, so you will be saying that **STARTING AT 768px & BELOW**.

**I made a CodePen so you can understand it better: https://codepen.io/hk95/pen/xoqWqe**

Hope this can help you, and if you have any doubts, please, let me know!
Have a nice day.

Comment: Ok, here's what I did. But this still isn't working. I'm trying to build for mobile first. The default property should be what I start with and overrides with media queries. This isn't my first time doing this. But for some reason I'm just not getting this right!
>@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  h1.logo {font-size: 2em;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  h1.logo {font-size: 1.25em;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1130px) {
  h1.logo {font-size: 1.2em;}
}
`

Comment: No worries, Jeff.
I'll try to replicate your comment in my CodePen.

Comment: Here, it's not letting me edit it.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JeffSydor/6png7mez/3/)

Comment: I mean, from what I understood and you sent me, `font-size: 2em` is being applied from 0px to 767px, then, `font-size: 1.25em` from 768px to 1129px and `font-size: 1.2em` from 1130px and beyond. So, just for me to understand, what's the problem with it?

Comment: the problem is that at sizes from 0-767, it's not recognizing the 2em. Instead it's just ignoring that line and applying the 768+ one of 1.25em. If there's something wrong with my code I need to know now before proceeding.

Comment: That's really strange, because when I used the inspector in your fiddle, I saw the selectors changes happening, I mean, there's nothing really wrong with your code, you know?

Comment: Take [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=tryresponsive_mobilefirst) for example from w3schools. I'm basically doing the same thing where I start laying out my code for mobile first, then use MQs for larger and larger breakpoints. But for some reason, once a MQ is defined, the default style is overridden.

Comment: Got it, Jeff. If you're saying the that the default style is your code that is not written inside MQs, yes, they will be overwritten because MQs have priority with selectors. If you inspect the code using your browser, you'll see that in W3Schools example this is also happening, since they're overwriting the `[class*="col-"]` with a `min-width: 768px` media query.

Comment: yes, I know. That's what i'm trying to do. But the default (767 & below) is being overridden when it's not supposed to be. It would be like if [class*...] was just being ignored by the browser. That's what's happening to me.

Comment: Ok I think I've narrowed this down to an error in the inspector window for Chrome. For some odd reason, the "Device Toolbar" option is ignoring the initial style and instead jumping right to the first media query.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answered, I wasn't able to do it, but I'm glad that you found how to solve the problem. Thanks for the feedback by the way, @JeffSydor :)